# custom style to stripe elements on angular 6 not affecting on UI

Tags: angular, angular6, stripe-payments

I have implemented stripe elements in angular. By default it is generating in one row, like card number in left align and expiry month and cvv in right alignment.

My requirement is that **card number text box should be in one row and expiry month and cvv text box in another row.**

I tried by looking this link: https://alligator.io/angular/stripe-elements/

Following is my code:

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_*************'); // use your test publishable key
    var elements = stripe.elements();
  </script>
```

**template file where I want to make design:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(checkout)" #cardInfo id="creditCardInfo">
    <div mat-dialog-content *ngIf="name==='credit'" >
        <div class="row" align="center">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                 <form class="example-form">
                      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                       <input matInput="number" placeholder="Card number" id="cardnumber">
                       </mat-form-field>
                  </form>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" align="center">  
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">                   
                <form class="example-form">
                     <mat-form-field class="example-half-width">
                         <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Expiration date" [formControl]="monthpicker">
                       <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"> 
                       </mat-datepicker-toggle>
                       <mat-datepicker #picker (monthSelected)="monthSelected($event)" startView="multi-year"></mat-datepicker>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-half-width">
                        <input matInput="number" placeholder="CVV" [formControl]="cvvnumber" id="cardnumber">
                       </mat-form-field>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div mat-dialog-actions *ngIf="name==='credit'">
          <div class="row" align="center">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
                  <div class="Rectangle-3">
                      <button cdkFocusInitial class="checkout" type="submit">CHECKOUT</button>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center" style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px">
                  <div class="Within-tap-checkout">
                     <span>Within tap checkout it means you agree with <span style="color:#76a6ef">Terms & Conditions</span> </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**ts file:**

```
  @ViewChild('cardInfo') cardInfo: ElementRef;
  date = new FormControl();

  card: any;
  cardHandler = this.onChange.bind(this);
  error: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    elements.hidePostalCode = false;
    this.card = elements.create('card');
    this.card.mount(this.cardInfo.nativeElement);

    this.card.addEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.card.removeEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
    this.card.destroy();
  }

  onChange({ error }) {
    if(error) {
      this.error = error.message;
    }
    else {
      this.error = null;
    }

    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  async onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log('form data... ', form);
    const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(this.card);

    if(error) {
      console.log('something wrong.. ', error);
    }
    else {
      console.log('token... ', token);
    }
  }
```

**css file:**

```
  form#creditCardInfo .row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }

  form#creditCardInfo .col-lg-12 .col-md-12 .col-sm-12 .col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  form#creditCardInfo .example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 80%;
  }

  form#creditCardInfo .example-full-width {
    width: 80%;
  }
```

Nothing is affecting. Please let me know where I am mistaken. Please help me out..

Comment: can you share a MVCE on stackblitz - that'll make it easier to help